Automatically Add a Little Extra Space between Italicized and non-Italicized Words to Facilitate PDF Conversion to eBook
I have been working on converting a PDF produced by Latex into an ebook.
What a mess!
I have since made the following adjustment:
\documentclass[ebook,a6paper]{book}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

And the result seems to be much better---but with many things that still need to be adjusted.
One of the frequently occurring problems is that two consecutive words (one italicized and the other not) are concatenated.
MWE:
\documentclass[ebook,a6paper]{book}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

I would like to \textit{add a little extra spacing} between any pair of consecutive words where one word is italicized and the other is not. (In this case, between `to' and \textit{`add,'} as well as between \textit{`spacing'} and `between.')
\end{document}

and its output:

How may I, when italicizing text, add a little extra PDF space between any pair of consecutive words---one of which is italicized and the other is not?
(I am hoping that the Amazon software to convert a PDF into a Kindle ebook will then not concatenate such words.---There does not seem to be a problem on that end when a comma is appended to either word.)

XY question? Since the latex code is good, as well as the pdf output, the true issue seems what you are doing to convert  it to an eBook, but you not show any clue about it.

@Fran I'm sorry; I do not know what "XY question" means. Also, perhaps you will clarify what you mean by "clue about it?"

The XY problems are well explained in the Wikipedia.  In brief, It seems to me that you are making the  question about your attempted solution (X) rather than the root problem itself (Y). Maybe, if you explain what are you doing exactly to obtain text with words crammed together (Y), so we can reproduce exactly the problem,  someone can propose a solution to Y (the wrong export to ebook). instead to X, that seems fixing a mess with another, i.e., mess a clean latex text with spurious spaces to fix the final format.

The font already specifies an italic correction for each letter. If you add \showoutput to your document you will see
....\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 s
....\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 p
....\kern-0.51112
....\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 a
....\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 c
....\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 i
....\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 n
....\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 g
....\kern 0.88472
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 b
....\kern0.27779
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
....\kern-0.27779
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 w

showing 0.88472pt has been added after the italic g/
The LaTex \text.. commands all add italic correction at the start or end of changing into or out of italic, although how much space is actually added depends on the font in use.
If you want more space, it depends what you want, for example you could use \myit{add a little extra spacing}  defined as
\newcommand\myit[1]{\hspace{.2em}\textit{#1}\hspace{.2em}}


I tried inserting \showoutput in the preamble, and then after \begin{document}. In both cases, I could not find the output you describe. (1) Where should I place the \showoutput command? and (2) where do I look for the output?

it writes to the log file @Jethro

Many thanks! (as well as for your answer)
